# How to calculate new price for reverse split?

Tags: stocks, calculation, stock-split

I have the following position

ABC 500 shares @ $120.00

ABC is trading at $15.00.  $60000 - $7500 = -$52500

ABC did a reverse split 1:5.  An 80% decrease in shares.  After the split, it is trading at $40.

How do I calculate the updated position based on my existing average price?  I know it results in 100 shares but I'm not sure about the price.

Comment: So why did the stock price drop from $120 to $15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You paid $60000 for your shares. You now have 100 shares, so your price per share is $600, i.e., 5 times the price you paid.

Another question here is why a 1:5 reverse split only increased the price to $40; 5 times the $15 pre-split value is $75.